# php: How to add days in this format ("01_Mar_2016")

Tags: php, date

When i try to add days in date in this format 2016-03-01, it add correctly but when i try to add in this format "01_Mar_2016". It gives me this input:

> 01_Jan_1970

```
<?php
$Date = "01_Mar_2016"; //2016-03-01
echo date('d_M_Y', strtotime($Date. ' + 20 days'))."<br>";
echo date('d_M_Y', strtotime($Date. ' + 2 days'));
?>
```

Comment: your $Date format is not valid

Comment: why are you using _ in your dates ?

Comment: you use - in d-m-y format

Comment: Alright thanks. When i changed underscore with - now its working

Comment: @john-conde It is not a duplicate of that question. The issue here is not related to how to add a number of days, it is a parsing problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
<?php
$Date = str_replace('_', ' ', "01_Mar_2016"); //2016-03-01
echo date('d_M_Y', strtotime($Date. ' + 20 days'))."<br>";
echo date('d_M_Y', strtotime($Date. ' + 2 days'));
?>
```

I think the underscores makes `strtotime()` fail to understand your format.